# Custom taxonomy term as class?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I'm trying to add a class to a container within a query, ideally I'd like to use the terms from a custom taxonomy I have setup (guide-categories).

As an example:

```
<div class="myclass *taxonomy term*">
  -content-
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, been looking around trying to find out how to do this for a while, but haven't had any luck yet!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name' ); ?>
<div class="myclass<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo ' ' . $term->slug; ?>">
    <!-- content -->
</div>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

Comment: Thanks! this works but would it be possible to show the term slug rather than name? (otherwise I get caps and spaces in some terms)

Comment: Yeah definitely, you could use `$term->slug` instead of `$term->name`.