# Append taxonomy terms as class names in markup?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, functions, custom-taxonomy

I've defined a custom post type for "person", and I'd like to append class names to the output markup based on taxonomies that correspond to team names. For example, if a person is part of the "creative" and "interactive" teams, I'd like to output the following:

```
<div class="person creative interactive">Jane</div>
```

I found [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39718/custom-taxonomy-term-as-class) on the forum, but in my case I need to output the taxonomy names within an `echo` statement, as the output is defined as a function in my `functions.php` file.

Here is a reduced version of what I've come up with so far, based on the aforementioned thread and [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197581/php-how-to-use-foreach-loop-inside-an-echo-statement):

```
function display_all_people() {
    // set up arguments for new post query
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'people',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
        'meta_key'   => 'last_name'
        );

    $peoplePosts = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $peoplePosts->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<div class="people-listing">';
        while ( $peoplePosts->have_posts() ) {
            $peoplePosts->the_post();
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'teams' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                echo '<div class="person' . implode('', $term->slug) . '">';
            }

            echo '<div>More markup for each person listing</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        } 
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        return '<p>Nothing Here.</p>';
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Thus, I'm trying to use the `implode()` to concatenate the values of the array (i.e. "team" taxonomy names), but it doesn't seem to be working (PHP is throwing errors.) Any idea how I can successfully append the taxonomies as class names in this way? Thanks for any assistance here.

Comment: Create an array of values first, and echo the implode after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differ the output until you have a collection ready.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'teams' );

// create a collection with your default item
$classes = array('person');

foreach ($terms as $term) {

    // add items
    $classes[] = $term->slug;

}

// output all the classes together with a space to separate them.
echo '<div class="' . implode(' ', $classes) . '">';

echo '<div>More markup for each person listing</div>';
```

---

### EXCLUDING

To ignore adding any item:

```
if( $term->slug !== 'accounting' ) { $classes[] = $term->slug; }
```

To remove all bad apples:

```
$pros = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$cons = array('C');
$best = array_diff($pros, $cons);
print_r ($best); // A, B
```

---

In context:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'teams' );

// create a collection with your default item
$classes = array( 'person' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $classes[] = $term->slug; // add items
    }
}

// remove any specific classes here
$classes = array_diff( $classes, array( 'creative-services' ) );

// output all the classes together with a space to separate them.
echo '<div class="' . implode( ' ', $classes ) . '">';

echo '<div>More markup for each person listing</div>';
```

Comment: so I just tried your approach, and it seems to be working as far as adding the class name defined as a default-- i.e. "person"-- but it's not adding those defined by the custom taxonomy. I'm wondering if there's something wrong with my the way I'm trying to collect the terms, i.e. `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'teams' );`?

Comment: I actually just figured it out-- first off, I was referencing the taxonomy name incorrectly-- it's "team" not "teams"-- and I need to wrap the `foreach` loop in an `if` statement in case no taxonomy terms have been defined for a given post. Now it's all working-- thanks again.

Comment: one other quick question on this topic-- can I easily *exclude* a specific taxonomic group, let's say "accounting" within "teams" (and show all other groups) in creating the array as above?

Comment: `if( $term->slug !== 'accounting' ) $classes[] = $term->slug;`

Comment: Added an `array_diff()` example above as well.

Comment: Hm, for some reason, the way I have this implemented isn't working-- I had to wrap it in an `if` statement to avoid errors, so I have it like this: `if($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
     if( $term->slug !== 'creative-services' ) $classes[] = $term->slug;
    }
   endif;` I must be making a mistake here...

Comment: Just add some curly braces after the conditional. Updated the code above.

Comment: strange, still not excluding-- in this case, the slug is "creative-services"; I've updated my conditional as follows: `if($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) :
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
     if( $term->slug !== 'creative-services' ) { $classes[] = $term->slug; }
    }
   endif;`

Comment: added another example. You should be able to remove a item from the array afterwards

Comment: thanks again for all your help. What I'm realizing is that the current `array_diff` approach is removing the selected *class* from the markup, but not the actual *post* associated with that taxonomic term. Not sure if it somehow needs to be used with `get_the_terms` or somewhere else in the query?

Comment: `selected class`?

Comment: I basically need to somehow limit the query itself to posts with all the taxonomic terms associated with "team" *except* for "creative services" and then append those terms as classes, as you've described above. I'm seeing that with the `array_diff()` approach, we're just removing certain terms from the actual array of terms to be added as classes. My apologies if I wasn't more clear earlier.

Comment: "Any idea how I can successfully append the taxonomies as class names in this way?" I believe this solves the original question. You should make another question for your other issue -- as these answer aren't supposed to be too layered or support tickets.

Comment: Understood-- thanks for all your assistance, @jgraup